# Why did Laurent-Désiré Kabila start the Second Congo War?

Tags: africa, congo

During the Second Congo War, numerous Rwandan sources report that Laurent-Désiré Kabila commenced the Second Congo War. In contrast, other sources and Human rights activists stated Rwanda and Uganda backed Laurent-Désiré Kabila to invade Congo so that they can access the natural resources of Congo. My question is whether Laurent-Désiré Kabila began the Second Congo War, or was it a plan by Paul Kagame and Yoweri Museveni?

Comment: Are the options mutually exclusive, or just different ways of describing the events?  That is, the person wouldn't have started the war if he didn't know he had backing, the countries wouldn't have agreed to provide backing if they didn't expect to get something in return.

Comment: Your question is about the Second Congo War, but the content of the questions sounds rather like it is asking about the First (or the First and the Second) Congo War, since Kabila marched towards Kinshasa (~invaded) in the first Congo War and was the internationally recognized President of the DRC in the Second Congo War. Rwanda and Uganda backed Kabila in the First Congo war and opposed him in the second. It could need some clarification